# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - when trying to get data from REST api using Axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors, rest

My SpringBoot Application Code :

```
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have also implemented **Controller Method CORS configuration** as mentioned in https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

I am using this code snippet to add a response header to enable CORS after referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975135/access-control-origin-header-error-using-axios-in-react-web-throwing-error-in-ch).

```
    @ModelAttribute
    public void setResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    }
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54342285/14995508), I also tried adding these headers in my frontend in axios interceptors.

I have read a lot of answers on StackOverflow about the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/54342285#54342285), titled "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but still coudnt figure out how to solve this. I dont want to use an extension IN Chrome or any proxy or use a temporary hack to solve this. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed everything from my code snippets which was related to CORS.

Now, my application code looks like this :

```
public class ServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I also removed the Controller Method CORS configuration. **Simply I have put a `@CrossOrigin` annotation above all the controllers.**

Also added `httpSecurity.cors()` in WebSecurityConfig which is used for permitting HTTP requests. Below is the code snippet,

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable()    
    // have further lines of code for authentication.
}
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, except you have mapping for `addMapping("/**")` twice.
Internally `CorsRegistry` stores the mapping in the arraylist in ordered fashion so in the above case for any origin `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins();` is the mapping that is added last for all the paths.
Not sure why you have the line `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins();` removing it should solve your problem.
If you have some TODO on `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins();` just swap make it the line before `allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");` (although allowedOrigins() does not help any cause).

Final code will look like

```
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");

                /*Remove the below line**/
                //registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this but I am still getting the same error. Do I need to keep the headers in my axios interceptor? Since this is a response side header, I don't think it is doing any benefit on the request side.

Comment: You have to add mappings in response side headers, don't see why the above solution wouldn't work, DId you recompile and restart your spring server?

Comment: Can you post the Errors snippet you are getting ? If You are still facing errors, feel free to drop the repo link in the comments, will have a look at the codebase and suggest tweaks if any required.

Comment: Yes, I did restart the server. The error is the same as I was getting. However, I removed every bit of code related to CORS and did only a few changes and now it is working fine. Thank you for your help.