# How I can get response http url by axios in the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with axios in REACT, it works on local but does not work when I deployed it.
It say this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4JWT.png)

my Code :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; 
import axios from "axios";

const Home = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://recvueadmin.hellow.fr/api/question")
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }, []);
```

I have this for CORS in the back-end :

`app.use(cors());`

Comment: Possibly a CORS issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975135/access-control-origin-header-error-using-axios

Comment: Did you change the request URL for production

Comment: may be a [CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949594/axios-having-cors-issue)

Comment: I have this for Cors in the server : app.use(cors());

Comment: I have this code for CORS in the back-end : app.use(cors());